# should I upgrade to yosemite from mountain lion?

Tags: osx-lion, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I have an `Mac Air 2013 1.7Ghz` (Intel core `I7`) with `8Gb RAM` currently running
`Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.5`. I have read mixed reviews whether upgrading to `Mavericks` or `Yosemite` was worth while. Apparently, some claim the software is very buggy.
Is it safe to upgrade my mac to `Yosemite`? What matter to me is battery life
and ability to continue developing without any major hang ups.

Any advice appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mac` computers are always using last hardware and, accordingly, `OSX` versions do same in order to have best skills and features each year.

Thats great if you can afford a new machine each 2 years (I recommend Xmas time in order to catch new versions of the `OSX` and fixes in the hardware and some family presents to afford it :D ).

Knowing this **I would recommend to upgrade to [`Mavericks`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201364) version `10.9.5` but not to [`Yosemite`](http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-yosemite-faq/os-x-yosemite-compatible-macs-system-requirements.html).**

It's true that the [`Yosemite`](http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-yosemite-faq/os-x-yosemite-compatible-macs-system-requirements.html) compatibility exists, but I've found that **earlier `mac` machines** does not have the propper hardware and you experience some lacks in memory and graphics when upgrading more than one `OSX`. This, *of course* would affect your performance and battery life.

Example: if you bought your computer with `10.8` then I recommend limit of `OSX` upgrade to last `10.9`.

Comment: "Mac computers are always using last hardware". Rofl.

Answer (score 2):

You should see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-IA3m9dh4s
It's compare the 3 OSX you talk about.

And the conclusion is that Mountain Lion is better in terms of performance and battery life